# Why does my ISP give me free Dynamic DNS service?

Tags: dns, internet, isp, wan, ddns

Recently when doing a reverse IP lookup on my own ip address I noticed that my hostname was set as `[insertAccountNameWithISPhere].plus.com` when I go to `plus.com` it redirects to Plusnet who is my ISP. Seeing as we have a static ip address and when I turn on my router then turn it off again the link still redirects to my ip address.

Note: I have redacted the account name for privacy.

Do other ISPs provide this service? Are they mandated to in the United Kingdom? Why do they do this?

Thanks

EDIT: Just some additional info: My WAN IP address is dynamic. My ISP offers a static IP address as a premium service.

Comment: I think what you see is quite normal. Most users I know prefer their ISP to do this rather than create their own DNS service.

Comment: This would be a very unusual setup... Realize that if anyone got your iP address (not hard) they have your account name. And no, this isn't common, at least not anywhere in the US.

Comment: If you have a static IP address then this hardly qualifies as DDNS, given that the first 'D' stands for 'dynamic'.

Comment: As @TilmanSchmidt touched on, [DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) is only for modems not assigned a static WAN IP, so if you are assigned a static WAN IP by the ISP, DDNS isn't needed.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt: I believe the 'D' in DDNS is based on how the _DNS entry_ is updated and nothing to do with how often the IP address is changed. If the system is set up to automatically update the DNS entry every time the customer connects (as opposed to requiring a human to update it every time), then *that's* what makes it "dynamic DNS", and whether it keeps writing the same value every time or not isn't actually relevant. Just like DHCP configured to issue a fixed lease is still DHCP.

Comment: Thank you @user1686 for mentioning this I'll change the wording.

Comment: I've noticed whilst going on the website (https://www.grc.com/shieldsup) that it mentions that I have a "machine name" [insertAccountNameWithISPhere].plus.com and goes into some detail. This would imply that there is additional awareness about this implying that this is not unique to my ISP. 
Go to the webpage and scroll to the bottom.